# 'void' type not allowed here (java) error

Tags: java, types, void

Here is my code:

```
public void start()
{
  //If the gas tank and oil have more than nothing, and the transmission is in gear park, then the car can start
  if((gasTank.getGasLevel() > 0) && (engine.getOilLevel() > 0) && (transmission.gearPark()))
  {
    engine.startEngine();
    System.out.println("Engine is now on");
  }
  else
  {
    System.out.println("Please make sure your car is in proper gear, engine has oil and gas.");
  }
}
```

I keep getting `'void' type not allowed here` error. I am not trying to return anything so I know I don't need int, Boolean, double, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: Can you post the entire class? I think it is likely some typo or missing curly braces

Comment: Is the name of your class `start` by any chance?

Comment: Can you give the total class structure.

Comment: I think one of your method return type in if statement is void

Comment: Can you show us the method signatures inside if statement? Are they void?

Comment: Paste the exact and complete error message, and tell us which line in your code it refers to.

Comment: Voted to close: OP not coming back, question impossible to answer definitively as-is; everyone is just guessing.

Comment: Sorry, the problem was I did not have everything inside of a class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is not inside a class.

Try this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    // your method here
}
```

Comment: +1 - This is probably the issue. But without more code we cant be certain

Comment: This seems to be a legit reason!!

Comment: I've been getting downvotes too, for no reason as far as I can see. I suspect a troll.

Comment: Correct. without an enclosing class, he code gives: Illegal type: void, 'class' or 'interface' expected.

Comment: Downwote was for "IamAnoob". That's uncalled for.

Comment: Sorry!! This was for an assignment a friend had helped me resolve the issue shortly after posted.. this was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one or more of these methods might be void, but must not be:

```
getGasLevel(); 
getOilLevel();
gearPark()
```

They must not be void because you are checking values returned from them in the if statement.

Comment: Why mark this down? Leave a comment explaining what's wrong with the answer

Comment: I think this is a valid answer...

Comment: This does not give the error the OP was experiencing... Simple example: `public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
   if(getInt() > 0) {
    
   }
  }
  
  public static void getInt() {
   
  }`
it gives the error: `the operator is undefined for the argument types, void, int`
This is probably why you got downvotes.