# Void not allowed here. Changing element in ArrayList Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, constructor, void

I'm having a bit of trouble with something that should be pretty straight forward.  I keep getting a 'Void not allowed here' error when trying to change an element in my ArrayList using a method

```
public static void editDialog(int pos) 
{
    if(parcelList.get(pos).type==1)
    {
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(""+parcelList.get(pos).idNum);
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(""+parcelList.get(pos).zone);
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField(""+parcelList.get(pos).getWidth());
        JTextField field4 = new JTextField();
        JTextField field5 = new JTextField(""+parcelList.get(pos).getHeight());

        Object[] fields = 
        {
            "Please Enter New Box Details:\n", "\n",
            "Box ID:", field1,
            "Delivery Zone:", field2,
            "Width:", field3,
            "Length:", field4,
            "Height:", field5
        };

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, fields, "Amend Box Details:",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        System.out.println(field1.getText() + "" + field2.getText() + "" + field3.getText() + "" + field4.getText()
                + "" + field5.getText());

        String getZone = field2.getText();
        int id = Integer.parseInt(field1.getText());
        char zone = getZone.charAt(0);
        int width = Integer.parseInt(field3.getText());
        int length = Integer.parseInt(field4.getText());
        int height = Integer.parseInt(field5.getText());

        parcelList.set(pos,Parcel.newParcel.addBox(id, zone, width, length, height));

    }
```

the addBox constructor is as follows:

```
public void addBox(int id, char z, int w, int l, int h)
{
    parcelList.add(new Box(id,z,w,l,h));
}
```

All i need to do is change values at a specific position in the list.  Does anyone know why im getting this error?

The Parcel class

```
protected static ArrayList<Parcel> parcelList;
protected static ParcelList newParcel = new ParcelList();

public Parcel(int id, char z) 
{
    this.idNum = id;
    this.zone = z;
}

//default contstructor
public Parcel()
{
    this.idNum=0;
    this.zone='z';
    this.charge=0;  
    this.type=0;
    this.i=new ImageIcon("images/nullParcel.jpg");   
}

public double getCharge()
{
    return charge;
}

public boolean isLarge()
{
    return false;
}

public ImageIcon getImage()
{
    return i;     
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{
    return "Parcel{" + "idNum=" + idNum + ", charge=" + charge + ", zone=" + zone + '}';
}

public void setIdNum(int idNum) {
    this.idNum = idNum;
}

public void setZone(char zone) {
    this.zone = zone;
}
```

The ParcelList class:

```
ParcelList()
{
    parcelList = new ArrayList<Parcel>();
}

public void addBox(int id, char z, int w, int l, int h)
{
    parcelList.add(new Box(id,z,w,l,h));
}

public void removeItem(int b)
{
    parcelList.remove(b);
}

public void addTube(int id, char z, int l)
{
   parcelList.add(new Tube(id,z,l));
}

public void addEnvelope(int id, char z, char s)
{
    parcelList.add(new Envelope(id, z, s));
}
public void printString()
{
    for(Parcel p:parcelList)
    {
        System.out.println(p.toString()+"");
    }
}   


public boolean isFull()
{
    if(parcelList.size()<=11)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void clearList()
{
    parcelList.clear();
}

public String listSize()
{
    return ""+parcelList.size();
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return this.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AssetList{" + "assetList=" + parcelList + '}';
}
}
```

Comment: What do you think `set` does? What arguments do you think it should take? Why do you think so? What do you think the error means?

Comment: I hope this answer should help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019723/void-type-not-allowed-here-java-error?rq=1

Comment: i thought that the .set method will set the current element to whatever new element i pass in?  As far as the error im at a loss, thats why i posted here.

Comment: Which class does `addBox` belong to? What is the code of `ParcelList`?

Comment: addBox belongs to ParcelList, ive edited original post.

Comment: bean, for them to see that you have made changes, you need to tag them like so @BeanShares where the name following @ is a user's name.

Answer (score 1):

Your `parcelList` is defined like this:

```
protected static ArrayList<Parcel> parcelList;
```

Which means that it is an `ArrayList`. Now, the method `set` in `ArrayList`, if you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)), needs one parameter which is an integer (the position), and another which is the base type of the `ArrayList` - in your case, a `Parcel`.

Your `pos` is an `int`, so that is good, but what are you passing in the `Parcel` parameter?

```
parcelList.set(pos,Parcel.newParcel.addBox(id, zone, width, length, height));
```

You are passing the result of the expression `Parcel.newParcel.addBox(id, zone, width, length, height)`. So this is a call to your `addBox` method.

That method is defined like this:

```
public void addBox(int id, char z, int w, int l, int h)
```

An expression which is a call to a method is considered to be of the type defined for that method. Your method is defined to return **`void`**. It means that it doesn't actually return *anything*. A `void` is *not* a `Parcel`, and therefore you get that error.

If you want to change the content of that position in the list, you'll have to pass an expression that actually returns a `Parcel` of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
Parcel.newParcel.addBox(id, zone, width, length, height)
```

needs to return something for the second argument in

```
 parcelList.set(pos,Parcel.newParcel.addBox(id, zone, width, length, height));
```