# Package in java says void is not allowed here

Tags: java, package, void

this is A.java

```
package pack;
import java.util.*;
class A
{
    public void msg()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
    public void add(int num1,int num2)
    {
        System.out.println(num1+num2);
    }
}
```

This is B.java

```
package pack;
class B
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A obj = new A();
        System.out.println("30+20=" +obj.add(30, 20));
        ob.msg();
    }
}
```

pack\B.java:7: error: 'void' type not allowed here
System.out.println("30+20=" +obj.add(30, 20));
^
pack\B.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
ob.msg();
^
symbol:   variable ob
location: class B
2 errors

i keep getting this error

I have made a file named pack and added A.java and B.java inside of the file
I am compiling it by
....Desktop\java class\tut4\mypackage>**javac pack*.java**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Void not allowed here. Changing element in ArrayList Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30357301/void-not-allowed-here-changing-element-in-arraylist-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj.add(30, 20)` refers to your `add` method in your `A.java` file. The return type of this add method is `void`. Think it through - what does `a + b` mean when `b` is of type `void`? Hopefully you see why this code doesn't compile and why you get this exact error. If you don't get it - then you may need to review what `void` means, as evidently it's confusing you. (`void` means that **nothing is returned** - it has no value. Hence any attempt to treat it as a value, which is obviously neccessary if you want to add it to something, cannot work).

Comment: oh right you made me aware of it. I have changed it to public int but now i am getting these errors pack\A.java:8: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
pack\A.java:12: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
pack\B.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        A obj = new A();
        ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
pack\B.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        A obj = new A();
                    ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
pack\B.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        ob.msg();
        ^
  symbol:   variable ob
  location: class B

Comment: At some point the advice just becomes 'go learn java'.